# Including just selected .so libs in apk

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, build.gradle

I have several .so libs in my *jniLibs* directory (let's call them *lib1.so*, *lib2.so*, *lib3.so*), which I use for *Project1*.

I use `jniLibs.srcDir 'path/to/my/dir/jniLibs'` setting in `build.gradle`.

I use the same *jniLibs* directory for *Project2*, but I only need *lib1.so* in this project.

Is there a way to say Gradle, that only *lib1.so* should be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have [packagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html) for that, e.g.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude "**/lib2.so"
}
```